# Saving searches from searchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` set up in my table VC and works as expected.

However, I want to be able to save the text from searches (i.e. after they press 'search' or 'enter' on keyboard) into an array.

I couldn't find anything relevant here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar?language=objc and suspect the solution will involve stuff with the keyboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [`searchBarSearchButtonClicked:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624294-searchbarsearchbuttonclicked?language=objc) and/or [`searchBarTextDidEndEditing:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624301-searchbartextdidendediting?language=objc) on your `searchBar`'s `delegate`. These method are called whenever the user presses the search button or finishes editing the text in the search bar, respectively

Comment: Thanks! I originally tried that but forgot to set up the delegate. So others know `class YourSearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {` and `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self`

Answer (score 1):

There is delegate:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

Inside this delegate method add `searchBar.text` into your desired array.